# Dante socks server on VPS doesn't work

Tags: vpn, proxy, socks, dante

My config on server side (/etc/danted.conf):

```
logoutput: stderr

internal: eth0 port = 1080
external: eth0

clientmethod: none
socksmethod: username none

client pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0  to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: connect error
}

socks pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: error connect disconnect
}
```

It seems that is receives the connection attempt from client because it logs something like this:

```
Aug 20 00:26:00 (1566275160.525913) danted[1316]: info: pass(1): tcp/accept [: 111.111.111.111.7606 222.222.222.222.1080
```

(111.111.111.111 is my client IP)

And it halts there until the connection is timed out.

I tried many config tweaks but all with the same result.

Comment: What connection times out? The one established by the server to the client requested address or the client server one?

Comment: @Ginnungagap I discovered that there is a general problem with my VPS. I tested a very simple python socket program and there are problems like data sent by client never received by the server side (It waits for data indefinitely after initial TCP connection, exactly like the dante server). I don't know the reason; Any idea?

Comment: How do you connect to your VPS? If you're SSHing into it, I'm assuming you have more firewalling issues than connectivity issues.

Comment: @Ginnungagap yes I am using SSH and it works without problems. Also apache/http works without problems, so i stopped apache and started my test python socket program on port 80 but it got the same problem!

Comment: What distro is this, what version, what's your python test, what are your firewall rules?

Comment: @Ginnungagap Debian 9.4. How to tell firewall rules? Should i place my python code in an answer here or maybe it is better to start a separate question for it?

Comment: iptables-save and ip6tables-save should list your firewall rules. I'm not that interested in the script as much as did you test it elsewhere and saw it work?

Comment: @Ginnungagap it is a cheep VPS. I think it is very basic/bare; maybe even no firewall is in place (in my OS at least). iptables rules empty. that's weird that SSH & apache work but not some other programs even Dante shows the same symptoms. if i cannot solve the problem i think the next logical step would be trying another distro. then if the problem persists, after contacting the seller doesn't solve the problem, maybe should buy & try another probably better (more expensive :( ) VPS. anyway it is better to solve the problem or at least find the cause of it from an educational standpoint.

Comment: @Ginnungagap iptables-save and ip6tables-save gave me empty result.  and yes i tested my python script locally then uploaded the server side to my VPS (and of course i changed IP addresses in server and client accordingly)

Comment: @Ginnungagap i ran client.py on server side too and it worked there without problems. so seems there is no problem with my script.

Comment: @Ginnungagap see the answer i posted to my question

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys

I asked from the reseller guys about the problem and they say the cause is the restrictions our government has imposed on those servers to prevent circumventing internet filtering/censorship that exists in my country.

Apparently they use Deep packet inspection, so that is the reason why some protocols (At least SSH and HTTP) work while the others don't.